# How to add buy and sell signal to MACD 4C indicator?

Tags: pine-script

I want to add buy and sell signals to MACD 4C indicator. I applied it as I did with other indicators, but it signals every candle where buy or sell conditions are suitable. How can I fix these signals?

```
//@version=5
indicator(shorttitle='MACD 4C', title='4 colour MACD', overlay=true)
fastMA = input.int(title='Fast moving average', defval=12, minval=7)
slowMA = input.int(title='Slow moving average', defval=26, minval=7)
lastColor = color.yellow
[currMacd, _, _] = ta.macd(close[0], fastMA, slowMA, 9)
[prevMacd, _, _] = ta.macd(close[1], fastMA, slowMA, 9)
plotColor = currMacd > 0 ? currMacd > prevMacd ? color.lime : color.green : currMacd < prevMacd ? color.maroon : color.red
plot(currMacd, style=plot.style_histogram, color=plotColor, linewidth=3)
plot(0, title='Zero line', linewidth=1, color=color.new(color.gray, 0))

buy = currMacd > 0 and currMacd > prevMacd
sell = currMacd > 0 and currMacd < prevMacd

plotshape(buy,  title = "Buy",  text = 'Buy',  style = shape.labelup,   location = location.belowbar, color= color.green, textcolor = color.white, transp = 0, size = size.tiny)
plotshape(sell, title = "Sell", text = 'Sell', style = shape.labeldown, location = location.abovebar, color= color.red,   textcolor = color.white, transp = 0, size = size.tiny)

alertcondition(buy,  "Long",  "Long")
alertcondition(sell, "Short", "Short")
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eUp1Z.png)

I wrote buy and sell commands as I added to other indicators, but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Try when the condition is true, and previously the condition is **not** true
Something like that:

```
longCondition = buy and not buy[1]
plotshape(longCondition,  title = "Buy",  text = 'Buy',  style = shape.labelup,   location = location.belowbar, color= color.green, textcolor = color.white, transp = 0, size = size.tiny)
```

Comment: I know do that. But I don't know how to adapt it to this indicator